# Finding dimensions directly

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{V}\rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ be a linear transformation, with $\dim \ker T=\ell$. Let $\overrightarrow v_{1},...,\overrightarrow v_{k} \in \mathbb{V}$ be linearly independent vectors. Prove that dim$~$span$~ \{T(\overrightarrow v_{1}),...,T(\overrightarrow v_{k})\}\ge k-\ell$.

I can't seem to prove this in a direct way. I can take values for the dimension of the Kernel of $T$, for example:

$\dim\ker T=0 \Rightarrow~$span$~\{T(\overrightarrow v_{1}),...,T(\overrightarrow v_{k})\}=k$

$\dim\ker T=1 \Rightarrow~$span$~\{T(\overrightarrow v_{1}),...,T(\overrightarrow v_{k})\}=k$ or span$~\{T(\overrightarrow v_{1}),...,T(\overrightarrow v_{k})\}=k-1$.

In this fashion, I think there should be an easier way though.

Comment: Please refresh your MathJax. This is hard to read. You should not have this many dollar-signs in one line.

Comment: This is not true. Consider $T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $T(x, y) = (x, 0)$, $k = 1$, and ${\bf v}_1 = (1, 0)$. Then, $l = \dim \ker T = 1$ but $\dim \langle T({\bf v}_1) \rangle = \dim \langle (1, 0) \rangle = 1 \neq 0 = k - l$.

Comment: @Travis, Edited question, my bad. Meant to say $\ge$, you are completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** (1) The intersection of two vector subspaces of dimensions $p, q$ itself has dimension $\leq \min\{p, q\}$. (2) Apply the Rank-Nullity Theorem to $\langle {\bf v}_1, \ldots {\bf v}_k\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since $KerT$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{V}$ and the set {$v_{1},...,v_{k}$} as well, then dim KerT$\cap${$v_{1},...,v_{k}$}$\le$ min{$l,k$}. How should I apply Rank-Nullity to {$v_{1},...,v_{k}$} if it does not necessarily represent all of $\mathbb{V}$?

Comment: The span $\langle {\bf v}_1, \ldots, {\bf v}_k\rangle$ is a perfectly good vector subspace in its own right, and we can applying the Rank-Nullity Theorem to the restriction of $T$ to that space.

Comment: Having a go at it: dim{$v_{1},...,v_{k}$}=dim(KerT$\cap${$v_{1},...,v_{k}$})+dim span{$T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{k})$} $\Rightarrow$ dim{$v_{1},...,v_{k}$}$\le$min{$l,k$}+ dim span{$T(v_{1},...,T(v_{k})$} $\Rightarrow$ dim span{$T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{k})$}$\ge$dim{$v_{1},...,v_{k}$}-min{$l,k$}

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: So that's $k-l$ if $l<k$ and 0 if $k<l$?

Comment: Yes. Of course, the second case doesn't contain any information, as all vector spaces have dimension $\geq 0$.

Comment: Damn ok I get it all now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful!